# Program won't run, Java, StringBuilder, Array

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I am trying to get my program to run. However, I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Any help would be appreciated. I didn't want to include to much code; so, I only included the block that eclipse said was wrong.

This is the constructor for the puzzle class. `(java.lang.NullPointerException)`

I corrected the first problem and added "StringBuilder puzzle = new StringBuilder();." I now get these errors on the same line.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.setCharAt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.setCharAt(Unknown Source)
at Puzzle.<init>(Puzzle.java:55)
at PuzzleGameConsole.main(PuzzleGameConsole.java:22)
```

Line 55 is the original problem line. It's marked with "//eclipse had an error on this line"

code:

```
public class Puzzle
{

    private StringBuilder puzzle;

    public Puzzle(String theSolution)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < theSolution.length(); index++) 
        {
            if (theSolution.charAt(index) != ' ') 
            {
                puzzle.setCharAt(index, '-');  //eclipse had an error on this line
            }
            else if (theSolution.charAt(index) == ' ')
            {
                puzzle.setCharAt(index, ' ');
            }
        }
    }
}


public int guessLetter(char letter)
    {   
        int count = 0;

        for(int index = 0; index < solution.length(); index++)
        {
            if(Character.toUpperCase(letter) == solution.toUpperCase().charAt(index))
            {
                if (puzzle.charAt(index) == '-') 
                {
                    puzzle.setCharAt(index, letter);
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public String getPuzzle()
    {
        return "";
    }


    public boolean solvePuzzle(String guess)
    {
        if(guess.toUpperCase().equals(solution.toUpperCase()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }       
    }

}
```

The test is posted below. It has no problems.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PuzzleGameConsole
{
    private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";
    private static final String MENU = "(1) GUESS A LETTER (2) SOLVE THE PUZZLE (3) QUIT >> ";
    private static final String PROMPT_ENTER_LETTER = "\nENTER A LETTER> ";
    private static final String PROMPT_SOLVE_PUZZLE = "\nSOLVE THE PUZZLE> ";

    private static final int SELCTION_ENTER_LETTER = 1;
    private static final int SELCTION_SOLVE_PUZZLE = 2;
    private static final int SELCTION_QUIT = 3;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle("JAVA IS FUN");


        int selection = 0;

        while(selection != SELCTION_QUIT)
        {
            System.out.printf("PUZZLE: %s\n\n", puzzle.getPuzzle());

            System.out.print(MENU);
            selection = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();

            if(selection == SELCTION_ENTER_LETTER)
            {
                System.out.print(PROMPT_ENTER_LETTER);
                char letter = in.next().charAt(0);

                int letterCount = puzzle.guessLetter(letter);
                if(letterCount > 0)
                {
                    printMessageBox(String.format("YES! The letter %s was found %d time(s).", letter, letterCount));
                }
                else
                {
                    printMessageBox(String.format("Sorry, the letter %s is not available in the puzzle.", letter));                 
                }
            }
            else if(selection == SELCTION_SOLVE_PUZZLE)
            {
                System.out.print(PROMPT_SOLVE_PUZZLE);
                String guess = in.nextLine();

                if(puzzle.solvePuzzle(guess))
                {
                    printMessageBox("Congratulations, you solved the puzzle!"); 
                    selection = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    printMessageBox(String.format("Sorry, '%s' is not the puzzle.  Keep trying!", guess));
                }
            }
            else if (selection != SELCTION_QUIT)
            {
                System.out.println("INVALID MENU OPTION");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nGood Bye!");

        in.close();
    }

    public static void printMessageBox(String message)
    {
        char [] border = new char[message.length() + 4];
        Arrays.fill(border, '-');

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append(NEWLINE);
        result.append(border).append(NEWLINE);
        result.append("| ").append(message).append(" |").append(NEWLINE);
        result.append(border).append(NEWLINE);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Puzzle is a StringBuilder

Comment: That you never initialize!

Comment: You need to declare/initialize the variable `puzzle`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels good point, a bit confusing, so even he realises he is not getting an NPE now.

Comment: now your `puzzle` has been init but it has no `length` (i.e. it's empty) so trying to `setChar` at index 0 (or 1 or anything) will not work as it has no length. Hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` => you need to initialize your `puzzle` with a value for the `solution` to try to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that StringBuilder is initially empty and you can't set a value/character which doesn't already exist. The simple solution to what you are attempting to do is to use a regex.

```
private StringBuilder puzzle;

Puzzle(String theSolution) {
    // create a buffer where all non space are turned into -
    puzzle = new StringBuilder(theSolution.replaceAll("\\S", "-"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely that you never initialize puzzle, never assign to it a `new StringBuilder()`. i.e.,

```
StringBuilder puzzle = new StringBuilder();
```

e.g.,

```
public class Puzzle
{
    private StringBuilder puzzle = new StringBuilder(); // **** add this!

    public Puzzle(String theSolution)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < theSolution.length(); index++) 
        {
            if (theSolution.charAt(index) != ' ') 
            {
                puzzle.setCharAt(index, '-');  //eclipse had an error on this line
            }
            else if (theSolution.charAt(index) == ' ')
            {
                puzzle.setCharAt(index, ' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should inspect the line carefully that throws it, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: @user3417938: `"this does not work"` tells us little that helps us understand your problem. Assigning a viable StringBuilder object will surely cure you of your primary problem -- your NPE. If you're now seeing another problem, you'd best tell it to us in detail as an edit to your question. Details **are** very important.

Comment: @user3417938: I've re-reviewed your question. If you still are having problems, then you will need to tell us more. Understand that we can only see code that you show us, can only understand concepts and details that you tell us. The more we understand, the better we can help.

Comment: @user3417938: now you've got a new completely unrelated problem. So you should correct your comment. My answer ***did*** solve your initial problem. Please show which line throws your new exception. What test String do you use?

Answer (score 0):

**Why do NullPointerExceptions happen?**

A NullPointerException is caused by an attempt to dereference a
pointer that doesn't point to anything; the pointer is null. Here are
a couple of common scenarios where NullPointerExceptions can be found:

1. `String myString = null;`
2. `System.out.println(myString.length());`

Here a variable, myString, is declared and initialized to null on line #1. When line #2
attempts to deference the variable myString in order to print the
string's length, a NullPointerException is thrown because myString
doesn't point to anything.

1. `System.out.println(aMethodThatReturnsNull().toString());`

This second example is a little trickier. No variable was declared, but
there is still a pointer: the return value of the method
aMethodThatReturnsNull(). That fictitious (and seemingly useless)
method will always return null. As we saw in the first example,
attempting to dereference a null pointer and call a method on the
referenced object (which is null) results in a NullPointerException.

**How do you track down a NullPointerException?**

To find the source of a NullPointerException, start with the stack
trace. In your Java console or log file, you'll see something like
this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.foo.example.NullPointerExample.main(NullPointerExample.java:21)

The stack trace tells you what happened (NullPointerException) and
where (line 21 of NullPointerExample.java). Look at that line and see
if you can recognize one of the two patterns given above. Ask yourself
these questions:

1. Are you calling a method on a variable that might be null?
2. Are you calling a method on the return value of another method, where the first method might return null?
3. Are you absolutely sure the answer to the first two questions was "no?"

NullPointerExceptions can happen for
other reasons, but these two are by far the most common.

http://publicint.blogspot.com/2009/04/nullpointerexception.html

Comment: Your post really has helped a lot. My program had many NullPointerExceptions. I haven't fixed all of them; but I appreciate you taking the time to help me learn. Thank you!